# File Create/Write Issue In Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create and write to a file. I have the following code:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

def crawler(seed_url):
    to_crawl = [seed_url]
    crawled=[]
    while to_crawl:
        page = to_crawl.pop()
        page_source = urlopen(page)
        s = page_source.read()
        with open(str(page)+".txt","a+") as f:
            f.write(s)
            f.close()
    return crawled

if __name__ == "__main__":
    crawler('http://www.yelp.com/')
```

However, it returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adamg/PycharmProjects/NLP-HW1/scrape-test.py", line 29, in <module>
    crawler('http://www.yelp.com/')
  File "/Users/adamg/PycharmProjects/NLP-HW1/scrape-test.py", line 14, in crawler
    with open("./"+str(page)+".txt","a+") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://www.yelp.com/.txt'
```

I thought that `open(file,"a+")` is supposed to create and write. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "No such file or directory: 'http://www.yelp.com/.txt'" You mean this directory doesn't exist?

Comment: Ugh, is the slash making a directory?

Comment: yep, it's because of the forward slash.

Comment: I knew it was something dumb. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the URL as the basis for the directory, you should *encode* the URL. That way, slashes (among other characters) will be converted to character sequences which won't interfere with the file system/shell.

The `urllib` library can help with this.

So, for example:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.quote_plus('http://www.yelp.com/')
'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yelp.com%2F'
```